# Adobe Air application and {StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN}

Tags: apache-flex, flash, air, fullscreen

I have problem with using next two properties together in one Air application, I need some functionality for show my application in full screen and scale for different displays. I mean , if user has  17" and other has 24" display my app should save proportionals. So, I've start to use these two properties StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN and see that internal canvas (buffer) is bigger than external,  please see on the pictures the firs just StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN and the second StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN and StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL.
[image: First Picture]

[image: Second Picture]

Could you help me and say How to fix this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have developed my own approach for re-sizing without using SHOW_ALL property, but currently it correctly works only on the Windows systems.

Answer (score 0):

StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL ensures the entire content of your Flash Movie is always displayed.  Depending on how large your content is, and where you place your images, this might well exceed the actual display width of your screen.

If you want your movie to always center on screen, but not scale its content, do it like this (fullscreen on click):

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Test extends MovieClip 
    {
        private var content : Sprite;


        public function Test ()
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            content = new Sprite( );
            content.graphics.beginFill( 0, 1 );
            content.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, 200, 100 );
            content.graphics.endFill( );
            addChild( content );

            stage.addEventListener( Event.RESIZE, onResize );

            content.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick );
        }

        public function onMouseClick (ev : Event) : void 
        {
            stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
        }

        public function onResize ( ev : Event ) : void 
        {
            content.x = (stage.stageWidth - content.width) * .5;
            content.y = (stage.stageHeight - content.height) * .5;
        }
    }
}
```

Then attach all your elements to the content Sprite instead of the stage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, So, currently I understand why content is going to big size where I use StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL, The next question is how to set up content size to size display using StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use that?  If you keep stage size below the minimum display size your app is intend to run on, you should be quite safe doing it the way I have shown above.

Comment: But if you still do: Basically, you have to make sure none of your MovieClips extend beyond the visible boundaries of your stage, i.e. you don't have images or MovieClips larger than your desired stage, and none of them go outside of the visible area.  Otherwise the content will be scaled so that everything on the stage can fit on your screen. See this: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/StageScaleMode.html#SHOW_ALL

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here is that anything except `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;` will not report the **actual** `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.stageHeight`, but will instead return the width and height of the **authored** dimensions.